# Maven Wildfly error

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I converted my Dynamic Web Project to a Maven Project since I want to run it on a Wildfly on a Raspberry Pi 2.
The problem is that after I converted and tried to Run as Maven build it started to pop up errors and errors..
I spent some time working on them and it seems like stoped, Maven could initiate. The problem now is that when I try to run Wildfly on it it is outputting the following error:

```
14:02:35,247 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.2.Final
14:02:35,415 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
14:02:35,475 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) starting
14:02:35,999 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:131)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:357)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:299)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: WFLYCTL0083: Failed to load module org.jboss.as.weld
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.parseExtensions(ExtensionXml.java:155)
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml$DefaultExtensionHandler.parseExtensions(StandaloneXml.java:126)
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_4.readServerElement(StandaloneXml_4.java:218)
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_4.readElement(StandaloneXml_4.java:141)
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:103)
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:49)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:123)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: WFLYCTL0083: Failed to load module
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.parseExtensions(ExtensionXml.java:147)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: WFLYCTL0083: Failed to load module
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.loadModule(ExtensionXml.java:196)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.access$000(ExtensionXml.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml$1.call(ExtensionXml.java:127)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml$1.call(ExtensionXml.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: Error loading module from C:\Users\jose\Documents\Wildfly\ó\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\com\sun\xml\messaging\saaj\main\module.xml
    at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:228)
    at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:204)
    at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:170)
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleFinder.lambda$findModule$0(LocalModuleFinder.java:149)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleFinder.findModule(LocalModuleFinder.java:144)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.findModule(ModuleLoader.java:439)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModuleLocal(ModuleLoader.java:342)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:289)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addExportedPaths(Module.java:1230)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1122)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1449)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1477)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:225)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.loadModule(ExtensionXml.java:178)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.xml.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected content of type 'element start' named 'path', text is: '<path name="com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj"/>' (position: START_TAG seen ...</properties>\n\t<path name="com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj"/>... @29:43) 
    at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.unexpectedContent(ModuleXmlParser.java:257)
    at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleContents(ModuleXmlParser.java:538)
    at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseDocument(ModuleXmlParser.java:340)
    at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:226)
    ... 22 more

14:02:36,001 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
14:02:36,018 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0050: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) stopped in 9ms
```

Any help would be really apreciated. I've tried everything I found on google and nothing seemed to work.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your configuration xml files in your application could have an typo
look at the exception trace

`org.jboss.modules.xml.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected content of type 'element start' named 'path', text is: '' (position: START_TAG seen ...\n\t... @29:43) at`